# Why I can't do unix redirect in my C++ program?

Tags: c++, sh

If I do `ls &> A.txt` on Ubuntu directly (redirecting both standard outputs and errors), it works as expected. However, in my C++:

```
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    system("ls &> A.txt;");
    return 0;   
}
```

It doesn't work. The C++ program would just print all the files on console, nothing redirected to `A.txt`. Why?

Comment: Redirection works for me. Is A.txt at least being created for you?

Comment: @StephenNewell Created but empty. I suspect my code is not unix distribution independent.

Comment: `system` invokes via `/bin/sh`, so maybe try that and see what happens? On my system `sh` is a symlink to `/bin/bash`, so maybe on your system it's a less powerful shell. Based on `man system`, the command to test should be `sh -c 'ls &>/dev/null'`

Comment: What kind of redirection is `&>` and why do you want this kind?

Comment: Interesting, this works as you want on my macOS but fails on an ubuntu...

Comment: @ErikElmgren It worked on my development OS-X as well, then failed on my production Ubuntu too. That's why I posted the question.

Comment: @n.m. is correct, ubuntu's /bin/sh is not handling '&>' correctly, just remove '&' and it works

Comment: @ErikElmgren I want to redirect both standard outputs and errors.

Comment: @n.m. https://askubuntu.com/questions/625224/how-to-redirect-stderr-to-a-file

Comment: @ErikElmgren I want to redirect both inputs and errors. https://askubuntu.com/questions/625224/how-to-redirect-stderr-to-a-file

Comment: @SmallChess, my ubuntu's /bin/sh is dash, on macOS it's bash. `ls 2>&1 > A.txt;` works

Comment: @n.m. — I think you'll find `&>` is an C shell import into Bash: see [Redirecting Standard Output and Standard Error](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirecting-Standard-Output-and-Standard-Error)

Answer (score 1):

The command you are executing is:

```
ls &> A.txt;
```

In the shell language, redirections bind more tightly than the `&` operator. Redirections are part of simple commands, whereas operators such as `&`, `&&`, `||`, and `;` join together or terminate a list of simple commands. Furthermore, in a simple command, the command itself is optional; it is valid for it to consist solely of redirections. Therefore, your command executes `ls` in the background without performing redirection, and proceeds to open `A.txt` for writing, but without actually executing anything that could write to it.

Your program is doing exactly what it's supposed to do. But I think you want this:

```
ls > A.txt &
```